# Defining menu items in my template in Nuxt project with PrimeVue

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, primevue

**Is that possible for us to create our menu items in the template area, instead of the script area in PrimeVue?** The official docs shows how to create several different menus, but none of them have the menu items defined in the  area. Every single menu have their items created as an array of objects in the data() section.
I believe that creating them in the template area I'll be able to customize them better, for example adding more HTML tags such as for icons using external library etc.

**My primary goal** is to add icons from this nuxt-icon library to each menu item, but I can't do that because these icons need an  tag, and I don't know about a good and safe way to pass HTML (such the  tag) to the script section of my code to insert it on the menu items.

I was using Buefy before in my other projects and I was able to define my menu items in the HTML/template area easily, so I was wondering if I would do the same with PrimeVue

About my project: I'm using '**Nuxt 3**', '**PrimeVue 3.23**' and icons from '**nuxt-icon**'.

PrimeVue docs: https://primevue.org/menu

nuxt-icon docs: https://nuxt.com/modules/icon

I was expecting being able to do so by adding some kind of 'MenuItem' tag, but PrimeVue don't have these tags available to Vue, they have to other sister libraries like the PrimeReact.
An example of what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
<Menu> 
<MenuItem> somemenu item here </MenuItem>
<p> some item </p>
<item> some item here </item>
</Menu>
```